# How to get the start number and end number with prefix from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help I don't know what to write in the query.

I have a table with a column name number in this number column I have the unique generated number, I want to see what is start number and end number for the specific prefix that is entered before the number.

I don't understand what query can I perform.

```
|---------------------|--------------------|
|          id         |       Number       |
|---------------------|--------------------|
|          1          |  Mumbai-8959965    |
|          2          |  Mumbai-8959966    |
|          3          |  Mumbai-8959976    |
|          4          |  Mumbai-8959980    |
|          5          |  MPR-8640100576470 |
|          6          |  Mumbai-8959987    |
|          7          |  MPR-8640100576475 |
|          8          |  Mumbai-8959997    |
|          9          |  MPR-8640100576481 |
|          10         |  MPR-8640100576482 |
|---------------------|--------------------|
```

How can I get the value like :

```
|--------------------|----------------------|
|        start       |         end          |
|--------------------|----------------------|
|  Mumbai-8959965    |     Mumbai-8959997   |
|  MPR-8640100576470 |   MPR-8640100576482  |
|--------------------|----------------------|
```

Anyone can help, please.

Comment: So, there is always a hyphen between the prefix and the suffix?

Comment: If there is a special logic in a field, you should try to split it into several fields. Otherwise you can't use an index and you need to parse the content of the field. While `Mumbai-123456` can be splitted into Mumbai and 123456 using LOCATE function, `Pimpri-Chinchwad-123456` can't.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, there is always a hyphen between the prefix and the suffix.

Comment: @GeorgRichter What if I say I only want start and end number no prefix required in another column. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'Mumbai-8959965'),
(2,'Mumbai-8959966'),
(3,'Mumbai-8959976'),
(4,'Mumbai-8959980'),
(5,'MPR-8640100576470'),
(6,'Mumbai-8959987'),
(7,'MPR-8640100576475'),
(8,'Mumbai-8959997'),
(9,'MPR-8640100576481'),
(10,'MPR-8640100576482');

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(number,'-',1) a
     , MIN(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number,'-',-1)+0)start
     , MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number,'-',-1)+0)end
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY a;

+--------+---------------+---------------+
| a      | start         | end           |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| MPR    | 8640100576470 | 8640100576482 |
| Mumbai |       8959965 |       8959997 |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Working fine thanks.

Comment: Can you explain little about what is the "-1)+0" in MIN(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number,'-',-1)+0) and Max Line?

Comment: It silently converts a string to an integer. This is necessary because alphabetically, '120' (for instance) is less than '20'.

Comment: ok, thanks. that's helpful.